# Not able to find portal.json file on wso2 2.1

Tags: wso2

I am using [this link](https://docs.wso2.com/display/DS200/Troubleshooting+Guide#TroubleshootingGuide-Step3-UpdatetheKeyStoreFileandKeyStorePassparametersoftheTomcatHTTPSconnector) to fix error `hostname in certificate didn't match:`

I am able to do all steps except the last one where it is telling me to update the `portal.json` file.

I am using WSO2 2.1 APIM and in my case I am not able to find file `portal.json` at path `<PRODUCT_HOME>/repository/deployment/server/jaggeryapps/portal.json`.

Does anybody know why I am not able to find the `portal.json` file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are referring to Dashboard Server docs, not APIM docs.

This is APIM docs: https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM210/Changing+the+Hostname

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am still new to WSo2 so still I need to study more what different feature this tool provide.